# How to create an javascript array in my case?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I wanted to create a obj like the following:

```
var collection = [{
    'title': 'title1',
    'content': {
        'subtitle': 'sub1',
        'contents': 'sub content 1'
    }
}, {
    'title': 'title2',
    'content': {
        'subtitle': 'sub2',
        'contents': 'sub content 2'
    }
}, {
    'title': 'title3',
    'content': {
        'subtitle': 'sub1',
        'contents': 'sub content 1'
    }
}];
```

My array is like

```
var section = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    section['title'] = data.title;  //data.title represent title1 to title 3
    for (var j = 0; j < data.sections.length; ++j) {
        //data.sections[j].content represent {'subtitle':'sub1', 'contents':'sub content 1'}
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to adjust my codes to create obj like above. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work? Without seeing exactly how the data array looks like, I made some assumptions.

```
var section = [],
        obj,
        d,
        s;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
          d = data[i];
          obj = {};
          obj.content = {};
          obj.title = d.title;
              for (var j = 0; j < d.sections.length; ++j) {
                  s = d.sections[j];
                  obj[s.subtitle] = s.content;
              }

        section.push(obj);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce function like that, but you need to modify it:

```
var obj = arr.reduce(function(o, v, i) {
   o[i] = v;
   return o;
}, {});
```